# time-out in nest js interceptor

Tags: javascript, redis, nestjs, interceptor

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CacheService } from './cache.service';
import * as CircularJSON from 'circular-json';

@Injectable()
export class CacheInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly redisService: CacheService) {}

  async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const key = this.generateCacheKey(request);

    const cachedData = await this.redisService.get(key);
    if (cachedData) {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(cachedData);
      return of(JSON.parse(cachedData));
    }

    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(async (response) => {
        await this.redisService.set(key, CircularJSON.stringify(response), 24 * 60 * 60);
      }),
    );
  }

  private generateCacheKey(request): string {
    return `${request.method}_${request.url}`;
  }
}
```

this is my interceptor in nestjs which saves the response of APIs in Redis.
It works fine when the Record has not been saved in Redis,However , when the record is in Redis the API times-out and stucks.

I need the API responses with the saved response in Redis.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately that would stop the API from responding. Odd  that you're parsing the `cachedData` twice instead of `return of(parsedData)`, but it should be fine